# dbf to shp within BASH (ogr2ogr would be ideal)

Tags: shapefile, convert, csv, ogr2ogr, bash

I have a CSV with many points and attributes that I'm trying to convert into a shapefile but I'm having no luck. I have installed gdal-bin and can use my terminal environment to create a shapefile with `ogr2ogr`, but I'm not getting the desired outcome. I'm running the following:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" 5_2834k2-25_FAST.shp 5_2834K2-25_DataCompiled_K2.csv -progress -skipfailures -a_srs EPSG:4326 -nlt POINT
```

And I get:

```
"5_2834k2-25_FAST.prj" 1 KB
"5_2834k2-25_FAST.shp" 8 KB
"5_2834k2-25_FAST.shx" 6 KB
"5_2834k2-25_FAST.dbf" 7,625 KB
```

but despite having all my objects and all the features, my SHP has no geometry. It's extent is 0 and recalculating gives me NaN errors in Arc.
Now my source CSV does have a lat and lon column (two separate columns) and I've tried to glean from [other](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180741/populate-lat-long-using-ogr2ogr) [answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72649/ogr2ogr-specify-lat-long-order-on-conversion-to-geojson?rq=1) how to get ogr2ogr to see and interpret these values but I cannot.

For example, perhaps using this bit of sqlite to choose the columns:

```
-dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT easting_col as long, northing_col as lat, geometry FROM input"
```

and "SELECT lon as long [...]" from input where input is my CSV... but nope. I tried a two-step cheat, thinking I could provide the dbf or shp from the incomplete output of the first as that input in the second but no...

I've tried as well `GEOMETRY=AS_XY` and I'm reading the man pages, the `--long-usage` help file as well as [the GDAL ogr2ogr page](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) but I just can't come up with the proper syntax.

How can I do this? I'm very frustrated because my columns don't have elaborate names ('Lat' and 'Lon') so I figured it would be very straightforward.

Comment: Could you add the column names and one row of data? You can use some fake data if your own are confidential.

Comment: You might need to put up a csvt file to tell GDAL which columns to take as geometry. An extract of your csv data (with header) might help.

Comment: you definetely need to tell GDAL how to construct your points; there is no auto-detection of arbitrary numbers as geometries. Try with `"SELECT *, MakePoint(<e_col>, <n_col>) AS geometry FROM <input>"` (from the CSV).

Comment: There is a limited auto-recognition as documented in https://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html `Starting with GDAL 2.1, accordingly with the GeoCSV specification, the "CoordX" or "Point(X)" type can be used to specify a column with longitude/easting values, "CoordY" or "Point(Y)" for latitude/northing values and "WKT" for geometries encoded in WKT`. Other also documented alternatives are to tell X and Y fields with open options of to write a VRT file that takes care of mapping.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. @user30184 There is a lot of data but here is the first row and a few columns: 
`IDRndX latLonKey Lat Lon nomCat 1966-08-17_DS1036 1966-08-17_DS1037 1972-09-21_Landsat1 
2001  -9.44507 -60.7239 Forest F F F `
`latLonKey Lat` is sometimes empty. it is the lat multiplied by the lon, nothing fancy.
I definitely got the impression there was _some_ auto detection of geometry @ThingumaBob, and I was trying to fulfill those requirements but obviously falling short. I'll look into a cvst file for sure, since my layout should be fairly static, thanks @AndreJ.

Comment: So thanks again, all. The trick that did it was adding `-oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=lon* -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=lat*` i pulled out the sqlite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Success!
`ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" 5_2834k2-25_FAST.shp 5_2834K2-25_DataCompiled_K2.csv -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=lon* -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=lat* -a_srs EPSG:4326 -nlt POINT -skipfailures`

Referring to https://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html was the key, for me. I found the examples and language on that page more useful than https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html.

`-oo   NAME=VALUE: Input dataset open option (format specific)`